# How to calibrate a load cell?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I'm working with a load cell and HX711. There was no weight on the sensor but I kept getting strange values, I thought it was broken or something so I used my second load cell but the same thing happened again. 
I'm wondering what is wrong with it ?
If anyone have worked with it or have an idea how to work with it, please don't hesitate to give your opinions.

```
 #include "HX711.h"
#include <Wire.h> 

#define DOUT  A0
#define CLK   A1

#define DEC_POINT  2
#define STABLE  1

float offset=0;
float calibration_factor = 1;
//float real_weight = 1.560;//kg
float real_weight = 0.5;//kg

HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);

unsigned char state=0;
long  FindZeroFactor();
float get_units_kg();
void  ReadWeight();
void  FindCalibrationFactor();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Auto Calibrate Program");
  Serial.println("Send 'a' to Find Zero Factor (Please Remove all weight from scale)");
  Serial.println("Send 'b' to Find Calibration Factor (Please insert know the weight on the scales)");
  Serial.println("Send 'c' Show weight on the scales");
}
void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp=='a')
      state=1;
    if(temp=='b')
      state=2;   
    if(temp=='c')
      state=3;
  }

  switch(state)
  {
    case 0:
    break;
    case 1:
      FindZeroFactor();
   //   ReadWeight();
      state=0;
    break;
    case 2:
     FindCalibrationFactor();
     state=0;
    break;
    case 3:
      ReadWeight();
      delay(200);
    break;
    case 4:

    break;

  }
}

long FindZeroFactor()
{
     Serial.println("Find Zero Factor");
     Serial.println("Please wait .....");
     scale.set_scale();
     scale.tare(); 
     long zero_factor = scale.read_average(20); 
     Serial.print("Zero factor: ");
     Serial.println(zero_factor);
     return(zero_factor);
}

void FindCalibrationFactor()
{
  unsigned char flag_stable=0;
  unsigned int decpoint=1;
  for(unsigned char i=0;i<DEC_POINT+1;i++ )
    decpoint = decpoint*10;
  while(1)
  {
      scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor
      Serial.print("Reading: ");
      float read_weight = get_units_kg();
      String data = String(read_weight, DEC_POINT);
      Serial.print(data);
      Serial.print(" kg"); 
      Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
      Serial.print(calibration_factor);
      Serial.println();
      long r_weight      = (real_weight*decpoint);
      long int_read_weight = read_weight*decpoint;
      Serial.print(r_weight);
      Serial.print(" , ");
      Serial.println(int_read_weight);
      long x;
      if(r_weight == int_read_weight)
      {
        flag_stable++;
        if(flag_stable>=STABLE)
        {
          Serial.print("Calibration Factor is = ");
          Serial.println(calibration_factor);
          break;
         }
        }
       if(r_weight > int_read_weight)
          {
            x = r_weight - int_read_weight;
            if(x > 100)
              calibration_factor -= 1000; 
            else if(x > 100)
              calibration_factor -= 10;
            else
              calibration_factor -= 1;
            flag_stable=0;
          }
          if(r_weight < int_read_weight)
          {
            x =  int_read_weight-r_weight;
            if(x > 100)
              calibration_factor += 1000; 
            else if(x > 10)
              calibration_factor += 10;
            else
              calibration_factor += 1; 
            flag_stable=0; 
           }  
  }
}

float get_units_kg()
{
  return(scale.get_units()*0.453592);
}
void ReadWeight()
{
  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor
  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  String data = String(get_units_kg()+offset, DEC_POINT);
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.println(" kg");
}
```

Comment: Could it be power fluctuations or a dodgy ground?

Comment: Or could it be your (unspecified) circuit?

Comment: The typical examples show a zeroing on startup.  Once zeroed calibration can be as simple as a known mass, or several to check linearity.  If you have another scale found objects will do, otherwise you can get a crude kit of calibration weights.  If you have a beam sensor make sure it is not upside down.  Beware there will always be noise - you probably want some filterung in what you display, again see typical examples.

Comment: @Matt i'm aware of that and I checked everything

Comment: @Majenko what do you mean ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I found some code samples and i'm using one but now I'm getting zero even when I put a wait on the sensor. PS: i'm using a tension compression load cell

Comment: @geniusme I am saying maybe there is something wrong with the circuit you are using to interface your load cell to the Arduino - however you haven't shown us that circuit so we are unable to tell. Please show your circuit, and also your code. Without that we cannot help you.

Comment: @Majenko I'm wiring my circuit like this [link](http://www.naylampmechatronics.com/img/cms/Blog/Tutorial%20HX711/Conexiones.JPG)

Comment: @geniusme That means nothing to me. What are those connections? Where do they go? What is the circuit you have there? I assume there must be some form of Wheatstone bridge there somewhere, yes?

Comment: @Majenko yes it is

Comment: @Majenko I'm using a load cell to weight stuff that other board represent a A/N converter and an amplifier (the variation is very small so we need to amplify it to have a noticeable result)

Comment: Could you add some sample output to the question? In the question you said you were getting strange values, but in the comments you said you were only getting `0`s.

Comment: because I started using a library, now when I have nothing on the sensor t it display zero and when I put a known weight it gives me a value but not the weight. I'm trying to figure out a mathematical formula to give me the correct weight

Comment: Is the value consistent?  If it is, and you are in the linear range, then the mathematical formula is to multiply by a constant.  Are you asking how to calculate the constant?  If so, What is the known weight and what is the displayed value.

Comment: @DaveX I found the mathematical equation, thank you ! I was wondering if I have a lot of load cells, would I have to calibrate each one of them every single time?

Comment: @genuisme To get very high levels of accuracy, yes.  Load cells, and the electronics are subject to mechanical, manufacturing variation, creep, etc., and using a common calibration factor would make your systems susceptible to those factors.  For the highest levels of accuracy, you would recalibrate with known weight standards in the range of interest before measurement and then re-check afterwards for drift.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that about Load Cells that always comes to my mind is the circuit which amplifies the load cell's signal, Usually the load cell signal changes in a low mv range, so you have to put a high gain circuit in the way of the signal, which amplifies signal and NOISE. You have to use an instrumentation amplifier for this purpose, otherwise, your signal would become so noisy.

And try to implement a low pass digital filter too, it should compensate the fluctuations and would give you smoother signal.

Answer (score 0):

```
scale.set_scale(calibration_factor);
```

needs to be changed to :

```
scale.set_scale(calibration_factor/[the reference weight you have used]);
```

Comment: Hi Reza, and welcome to Arduino.SE! While your answer may be correct, it is a little terse. Could you expand upon our answer and explain why that change is required?